# Expand clickable region of thin div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Given JSX

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and CSS

```
.parent{
  position:relative;
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
 
}
.parent:hover{
  background-color:red;
}

.child{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  border: 2px solid steelblue;
  
}
.child:hover{
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-dream-hd3nbe?file=/src/App.js:0-142)

Is there a way to enlarge the clickable region of child div (in orange rectangle portion) without changing the look of div (expanded region needs to be in transparent)? Now it's too small to click.
[image]

Comment: You can set a width to increase the size.

Comment: @cloned changing width will change the look, I have updated the question to reflect that, expanded region needs to be in transparent.

Comment: The codesandbox does not show the example screenshot. Please add a [mre].

Comment: @0stone0 you need to mous over the small rectangle portion to see the screen shot. I have included all the required codes here, nothing extra.

Comment: It's an empty sandbox, even the styles.css is empty. Sure you've pasted the correct url?

Comment: @0stone0 can you retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.child::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 5px; // Give more size if you need
  height: 100%;
  //background-color: green; // Use this only to debug
}
```

This add a non visible rectangle that affect to your hover. You can also use `left` and `top` if you need move the rectangle.